# Visual c++ express 2010... :D Include path and release?

Tags: visual-studio, release, visual-c++-2010

hope this is not such a stupid question, but I just tried to compile under the "release" configuration a project of mine using Microsoft Visual C++ Express Edition 2010.
I need some files to be included, they are all in a directory, and I'd need to include them using the
`#include <myfile>` directive, with angle brackets. I managed to do it in debug mode, but I didn't find out how to do it in release mode..
Thank you very much, again sorry for the very elementary question!

Matteo

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the menu `Project -> MyProject Properties...`
2. Select the appropriate configuration (relase, debug, etc) in the top-left drop-down
3. On the left, navigate to `Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories`
4. In the main pane, edit your `Include Directories` as desired